# Align console windows at startup for multiple projects (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I have a 4 projects in a solution that each open its own console window.

When starting multiple projects in debug mode in VS, they get stacked on top of each other, but I want them to align at the corners (or similar).

Is there any way to control this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Do you mean automatically (via VS or plugin) or programmatically (from within your program)? If from within your program - see previous comment.

Comment: @m.rogalski, being console windows for 4 different processes, retreiving their HWND can be not so straightforward. Maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/124103/how-to-obtain-a-console-window-handle-hwnd) can be useful

Comment: @GianPaolo Why do you need it for 4 processes? This can be done inside each of the projects by simply getting `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` and setting up window position to one of the four available corners.

Comment: @m.rogalski, right, I was thinking about controlling the 4 console windows from "outside", but actually each process can set its console window position. Does MainWindowHandle works for a Console Application?